# Why when I changed the registry's location of my native app's manifest.json does Firefox not recognize the change?

Tags: firefox-addon, registry, browser-extension

I changed the registry's location of my native app's manifest.json in both
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\nativeappname`
and
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\nativeappname`
to
`C:\Users\myUser\Documents\nativeappname\manifestForFirefox.json`,
restarted, and Firefox is still giving the error
`Error reading native manifest file C:\Users\myUser\Documents\nativeappname\manifest.json: file is referenced in the registry but does not exist`
I tried deleting each of the keys above, recreating them, restarting, and still have the problem. Any idea why Firefox continues to give this error?

Answer (score 0):

So I searched in the registry for the path in the error and found a `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1337783450-3882494738-603851891-1004\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\nativeappname` key that still had the `C:\Users\myUser\Documents\nativeappname\manifest.json` path in it. I have not read or seen any documentation regarding this key's operation, and Google tells me the HKEY_USERS subtree is related to domain-controlled computers, but this is a home-pc running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044, and I don't have any domains set up (would appreciate any insight on this in the comments). Anyway, when I changed the path there, Firefox started messaging with the native app again.